# Determine whether a given JavaScript action has been initiated by user

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

Is it possible to determine whether a given JavaScript action has been initiated by user? For instance I want to know whether a link was clicked by user or via jQuery fire event method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`event.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) will be `undefined` if the event is triggered with code.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VYHmt/).