# Click source in JavaScript and jQuery, human or automated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click, dom-events

We all know that you can simulate click or any other event on an element using one of these ways:

```
$('#targetElement').trigger('eventName');
$('#targetElement').click();
```

I have encountered a situation in which, I should know how an element is clicked. I should know if it's been clicked automatically via code, or by pressing mouse button. Is there anyway I can do it without hacks or workarounds? I mean, is there anything built into browsers' event object, JavaScript, or jQuery that can tell us whether click has been initiated by a human action or by code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine whether a given JavaScript action has been initiated by user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948350/determine-whether-a-given-javascript-action-has-been-initiated-by-user)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#targetElement').click(function(event, generated) {
    if (generated) {
        // Event was generated by code, not a user click.
    } else {
        // Event was generated by a user click.
    }
});
```

Then, to make this work, you have to trigger them like this:

```
$('#targetElement').trigger('click', [true]);
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N9C8k/).

Comment: Thanks @cdhowie, but this is a workaround. I already knew that :). I'm trying to know if there is any built-in way for that or not.

Answer (score 6):

Check out [`event.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/), it'll be `undefined` if triggered with code.

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if (event.which) {
       // Triggered by the event.
    } else {
       // Triggered with code.
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/gB49u/).

Comment: Wrong. It's a jQuery object. The element has been clicked via jQuery using `$('#elementId').click()`.

Comment: Testing in Chrome, I actually had better luck using `if (event.srcElement)`

Comment: @josh.trow: I tried in Firefox and it doesn't seem to support that event property.  :(

Comment: @cdhowie: Ah, sorry event.srcElement is the old IE way, try using event.target maybe?

Comment: @josh.trow: `event.target` is set for both user and code-generated events on Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/3avtK/

Comment: @cdhowie: see my answer for a way I found

Comment: @cdhowie My memory had failed me. I have updated to what I use to determine if the click was user initiated or not.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way I have found (tested in Chrome)

```
$('#foo').click(function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent)
        alert('Has e (manual click)');
    else
        alert('No e (triggered)');
});
```

See here for testing:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZPD8w/2/

Answer (score -5):

In your immediate event handler, provide an `e` parameter. If the click is automated (via code), this e would be undefined (no need to check e.target as @alex has said):

```
$('#targetElement').click(function(e){
   if(e)
   {
      // Click is triggered by a human action
   }
   else
   {
     // Click is triggered via code
   }
});
```

Comment: I worked for me. I don't know what's different from @josh example. But in my case, it worked. However I revert marking this post as my answer.

Comment: @Saeed Neamati: I'm not checking for the existence of the `e` object itself, I'm checking for the field/value/whatever of `originalEvent`