# Is .click() an actual mouse click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Click source in JavaScript and jQuery, human or automated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982072/click-source-in-javascript-and-jquery-human-or-automated)

How can you check if a `.click()` is an actual mouse click or you just are calling `.click()`?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can.

But you can instead use a different event, like `mousedown`, but that could also be called manually as well.

Why do you need to differentiate between code-triggered and user-triggered events?

Comment: I need an alternative to e.stopPropagation();

Comment: It is possible, event.which is set to `undefined` when trigger by code.

Comment: @Exelian, I stand corrected. Cool. Tested at http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/zefXc/

Answer (score 0):

Set the action for the click event to call a function with the argument isClick=1. When you call the same function otherwise, call it with isClick = 0.