# How to distinguish program click from physic

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image and code

```
$(thisSrc).click();
```

How I can to distinguish physic mouse click by user

```
$(thisSrc).on("click", function () {
});
```

from program by javascript?

```
 $(thisSrc).click();
```

Comment: See also [Difference between .click() and actually clicking a button?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11127908/710446)

Comment: Also duplicate of [Determine whether a given JavaScript action has been initiated by user](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5948350/710446).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982072/click-source-in-javascript-and-jquery-human-or-automated   - really work for me. just pass in an argument. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `isTrigger` key in event when it's triggered.

```
$(el).click(function(e) {
   if (e.isTrigger) {
      // triggered
   } else {
      // clicked by hand
   };
});
```

Answer (score -2):

One way would be like this:

```
var realClick = true;

realClick=false;$(thisSrc).click();

$(thisSrc).on("click", function () {
// stuff
realClick=true;
});
```

Comment: But you would have to set realClick to false on every manual click.

Comment: I don't think you've understood the question correctly? I certainly don't see how this answers the question, anyway.

Comment: I don't think so, this works fine. Might be more elegant ways but this works...